# can't add Hebrew to keyboard layout

Tags: opensuse

I'm running on

> NAME="openSUSE Leap" VERSION="42.3"

I've added `Hebrew` as a secondary language but  in the `System Keyboard Layout` there is no `Hebrew` layout.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to `Configure Desktop` -> `Input Devices` -> `Keyboard` -> `Layouts` ,  there you can add a new Layout.

Comment: From the command line you can set `setxkbmap us,il -option "lv3:ralt_alt,grp:alt_shift_toggle"` - [see post](https://askubuntu.com/a/414866/890566)